# Blank lemmatization using spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How to use lemmatization in Spacy? I try with this code but the output is blank. My spacy ver. 3.2.0

```
from spacy.lang.id import Indonesian

nlp = Indonesian()

def tokenizer(text):
    return [token.lemma_.lower() for token in nlp(text) if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]


docs = [
    'Saya pikir ayah saya terlihat seperti Matt Damon.',
    'Tapi apakah rezim mempelajari sesuatu?',
    'Lalu dia mulai berjualan mariyuana.',
    'Apakah Anda ingin menjadi penerbit, seseorang yang memberi lisensi teknologi?',
]

for text in docs:
    print(tokenizer(text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the [lookup lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#lemmatizer-lookup). If you install `spacy-lookups-data` then you can do that like this:

```
nlp = Indonesian()
nlp.add_pipe("lemmatizer", config={"mode": "lookup"})
nlp.initialize()
```

Then you'll get this output:

```
['pikir', 'ayah', 'matt', 'damon']
['rezim', 'ajar']
['jual', 'mariyuana']
['terbit', 'lisensi', 'teknologi']
```